# Where have the Eclipse online javadocs gone?

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

For as long as I've been working on Eclipse plug-ins when I have wanted to read some documentation I have always just googled it. This worked fine up until about a week ago when I started being met with this message:

| Topic not found
The topic that you have requested is not available. The link may be wrong, or you may not have the corresponding product feature installed. This online help only includes documentation for features that are installed.

Today this has tripped me up on the following queries:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=ITreeContentProvider

http://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=IObjectActionDelegate

Sometimes trying different versions of the Eclipse docs works, sometimes it doesn't.

I had assumed this was just a glitch but I'm still noticing this issue, where have the docs gone?

Comment: really? i'm talking about the first links on google - to help.eclipse.org.

Comment: Yes. They were working yesterday and don't work anymore today. I guess you should open an Eclipse bugzilla entry for that

Comment: I have e-mailed the webmaster, I will update with what he says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved. I contacted the Eclipse web admin but didn't hear back so whether Eclipse fixed the issue or Google figured it out, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions without using Google:

1. Use the [Eclipse documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/documentation/) directly!
2. Use [Bkekko](http://www.blekko.com) with my Eclipse slashtag: https://blekko.com/ws/ITreeContentProvider+/timkrueger/eclipse

Comment: Unfortunately both of these suggestions suffer the same issue